# Scala: Can a generic trait take its generic type instance from its implementing class?

Tags: scala, generics, traits

Suppose I have the following trait:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def returnMyself: T
}
```

Is there any way that would tell scala that any class that extends `Foo` does so with *itself* as the generic parameter?

Basically, what I want to achieve is being able to write

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  override def returnMyself: Bar = this
}
```

without having to explicitly write

```
class Bar extends Foo[Bar]
```

I hope I've made myself clear

Comment: To clarify: is it required that `returnMyself` must yield the same instance? Or may it be another instance of the same class?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using self types:

```
trait Foo { self =>
  def returnMyself: self.type
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  override def returnMyself = this
}
```